# Cloned Form elements -> Ids updated with a number -> Get value of the dropdown

Tags: c#, jquery, function, clone, onchange

Cloned a form based on number selected in a dropdown. select and input fields ids on cloned forms are updated with a number such as OrderType1, OrderType2 etc....Now I need to retrieve the value of the dropdown OrderType1 and show a div.

Below is the code. Cloning works perfectly.

```
//DUPLICATE PLUGIN
            $.fn.duplicate = function (count, cloneEvents) {
                var tmp = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    $.merge(tmp, this.clone(cloneEvents).get());
                }
                return this.pushStack(tmp);
            };

            //SELECT CHANGE FUNCTION (on change get value and clone)
            $('#case').change(function () {  // on change...
                var numOfClones = $(this).val();    // get value...

                $('#holder').html('');              // empty holder if there are some old clones
                $('#caseNumber').duplicate(numOfClones).addClass('new').appendTo('#holder').show();
                $('#caseNumber.new').each(function (idx) {
                    idx = $(this).index() + 1;
                    $('select', this).each(function () {
                        $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + idx).attr('id', $(this).attr('name'));
                    });
                    $('input', this).each(function () {
                        $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + idx).attr('id', $(this).attr('name'));
                    });
                    $('#caseNumbering', this).each(function () {
                        $(this).text("Case Number " + idx++);
                    });
                });

            });






            $("#orderType-req1").change(function (event) {
                alert("You have Selected  :: " + $(this).val());
            });
```

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am working on a order form. There is dropdownlist of 10 case numbers. Below that there are fields which customer enter to place an order. Quantiies of each item and also orderType . If 4 is selected from dropdown, these quantities and ordertype are duplicated 4 time for customers to fill up for each case. Above code is used to duplicate caseNumber. and assign number value to ids for each field. Issue I am facing is orderType field which is a dropdown with Commercial and Other values. Say case2, customer selects Other, a hidden textfield is displayed for customer to enter details.

Comment: $("#orderType-req1").change(function (event) {
                if (this.value == 'Other:') {
                    $("#orderTypeOtherDiv").show("blind");
                } else {
                    $("#orderTypeOtherDiv").hide("blind");
                }
            });  //doesnt work  Before Clone, id is OrderType. So 4 clones means I have OrderType1, OrderType2, OrderType3 and OrderType4 and when these values are individually set some action is taken in jquery

Comment: how do I get the value of the cloned dropdown menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not certain that I understand perfectly what you are trying to achieve, but I think I've got the gist.

The trouble is that both the `id` and `name` attributes of your dynamically cloned Order Type `<select>` elements so that you do not have a static selector for which to bind an event handler.

My suggestion is to add an attribute to the original `<select>` that *will* be a static one that is common to all clones - for example, a data-attribute, like `data-order-type`.

Then, using Event Delegation, we can attach an event handler that will listen for changes to *any* `[data-order-type]` element and handle them accordingly.

```
$(document).on('change', '[data-order-type]', function () {
  const $this = $(this);
  const val = $this.val();

  $this.parent().find('.blind').toggle(val === 'Other');
  alert("You have Selected  :: " + val);
});
```

Added to your code, we get:

```js
$.fn.duplicate = function(count, cloneEvents) {
   var tmp = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
     $.merge(tmp, this.clone(cloneEvents).get());
   }
   return this.pushStack(tmp);
 };

 //SELECT CHANGE FUNCTION (on change get value and clone)
 $('#case').change(function() { // on change...
   var numOfClones = $(this).val(); // get value...

   $('#holder').html(''); // empty holder if there are some old clones
   $('#caseNumber').duplicate(numOfClones).addClass('new').appendTo('#holder').show();
   $('#caseNumber.new').each(function(idx) {
     idx = $(this).index() + 1;
     $('select', this).each(function() {
       $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + idx).attr('id', $(this).attr('name'));
     });
     $('input', this).each(function() {
       $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + idx).attr('id', $(this).attr('name'));
     });
     $('#caseNumbering', this).each(function() {
       $(this).text("Case Number " + idx++);
     });
   });

 });


$(document).on('change', '[data-order-type]', function () {
  const $this = $(this);
  const val = $this.val();

  $this.parent().find('.blind').toggle(val === 'Other');
  alert("You have Selected  :: " + val);
});
```

```css
#holder {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.blind {
  display: none;
}

.new {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="case">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>


<div id="caseNumber">
  <select data-order-type name="orderType">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>Other</option>
  </select>
  <input name="OrderType">
  <div class="blind">
    <p>
      This is hidden stuff.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="holder"></div>
```

Comment: can it be $this.parent().find('#orderTypeOtherDiv').toggle(val === 'Other'); which is set to display:none. but that doesnt work

Comment: I got it working with your code $(document).on('change', '[data-order-type]', function () {                
                if (this.value == 'Other:') {
                    $(".orderOther").show();
                } else {
                    $(".orderOther").hide();
                }
            }); But then Case2, case 3  also shows textfield when Other selected in Case 1. Case2 might be Commercial which should not show the textfield. Help needed.

Comment: @Leeya This is very difficult to troubleshoot without knowing your HTML structure. In order to limit what element is toggled to just a single clone, I was using `.parent()`. But your HTML may be different. If every clone begins with an element with class `new`, then you could try: `$(this).closest('.new').find('.orderOther').show()` (and similarly for `.hide()`).

Comment: <div id="caseNumber" style="display:none;"><div class="row" style="margin-left:1px;font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;" id="caseNumbering"><br /></div>
<div class="row form-group">
<div id="orderType" class="col-12 col-md-6">
 @RenderOrderTypeDropdownField(formFields.Find(x => x.FieldName == "orderType-req"))</div><div class="orderOther col-12 col-md-6" id="orderTypeOtherDiv" style="display:none">
@RenderTextField(formFields.Find(x => x.FieldName == "orderTypeOther"))
   </div>
  </div>

Comment: @helper RenderOrderTypeDropdownField(FormField formField)
{   <label for="@formField.FieldName">@formField.FieldLabel</label>

    <select data-order-type name="@formField.FieldName" id="@formField.FieldName" class="@(Page.Errors.Contains(@formField.FieldName) ? "error " : "form-control ")">
        <option value=""> </option>
        <option value="Commercial" @(fieldValue == "Commercial" ? "selected" : "")>Commercial</option>
        <option value="Other:" @(fieldValue == "Other:" ? "selected" : "")>Other:</option>
    </select>}

Comment: @Leeya My recommendation remains to to use `$this.closest('.new').find('.orderOther').toggle($this.val() === 'Other')`. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/Lno4h8fk/

Comment: It works like a charm. One more question: $(document).on('change', '[data-order-type]', function () {
                $(this).closest('.new').find('.orderOther').toggle($(this).val() === 'Other:');
                $(this).closest('.new').find('.commercial').toggle($(this).val() === 'Commercial');  //this works
            });  I need to hide .noncommercial when .val() === 'Commercial'); $(this).closest('.new').hide('.noncommercial').toggle($(this).val() === 'Commercial'); How do i acheive that?

Comment: @Leeya I think what you are asking for is: `$(this).closest('.new').find('.noncommercial').toggle($(this).val() !== 'Commercial'))`

Comment: Thanks for your help  Steve. All working as expected. All solutions provided helped.

Comment: @Leeya You're welcome. I would appreciate it if you would mark my post as the Accepted Answer.

Comment: Hi Steve - In debug mode testing, I entered 2 case numbers with details. It captured orderType1, orderType2 But then it was looking for orderType as well and threw error. All clone were added with number idx. So why is it looking for original fieldname quantities, ordertype-req etc.. What chnage is needed in cloning code?

Comment: @Leeya I am not sure what you are asking about. I don't know what you mean by "looking for orderType". Is this when you submit a form?

Comment: I figured that out. But now I facing another issue. When I submit the form, cloned forms values are not being recognized to be sent in an email. Email format is in another cshtml file.   <table>
        <tr><th>[case]</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Order type: [orderType-req1][orderTypeOther1]</td></tr>. I am getting Order type: [orderType-req1][orderTypeOther1] in email instead of their values. Non-cloned values are working as expected.

Comment: private static string GetMailContent(List<FormField> formFields)
    {

        string path;

        var emailViewName = "OrderFormEmailChina.cshtml";
   
       path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Views/" + emailViewName);

        string readText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);

        string mailContent = readText;

        string fieldContent = "";

        foreach (FormField formField in formFields)
        {

Comment: @Leeya How you are constructing emails in your server-side code is a very different issue. I suggest you create a fresh post for this.